# Vagrant: destroy not working

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, vagrantfile

How should I use the command `vagrant destroy`?

In my VagrantFile I used `vm.config.name = 'websvr'` and when I open Virtualbox I can see websvr on the list of Vm's.

But whenever I use `vagrant destroy websvr` it returns:

> The machine with the name 'websvr' was not found configured for this Vagrant environment.

How does `vagrant destroy` work?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It seems the item does not exist, but it appears in the list because it is present in the cache. Use `vagrant global-status --prune` to get rid of it.

See [vagrant global-status documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/global-status.html) for more details.

Comment: Please document any relevant code, as well as providing the link.

Answer (score 7):

Lets try these action in command line

- 1. Check available installed boxes by calling

     `vagrant box list`
- 2. Find box id

     `vagrant global-status --prune`
- 3. Select by id name of your box for destroying.

     `vagrant destroy 1a2b3c4d`

> Thats all for you. Now you can destroy your vagrant box `vagrant destroy xxxxxxx` by this command.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `vagrant status` first, which should list all of your VMs with their current status (running, not created, etc.)

The names of the VMs are displayed in the first column and are case sensitive.

For example, this is what the output of `vagrant status` looks like on my machine:

```
base                       not created (virtualbox)
git                        not created (virtualbox)
go                         not created (virtualbox)
dev_workstation            not created (virtualbox)
single_instance            not created (virtualbox)
metrics                    not created (virtualbox)
```

Comment: it only states 'default   poweroff (virtualbox)'

so would that mean that I should vagrant destroy default? But what if you have multiple vagrant running would that remove other vagrant boxes too?

Comment: Yes, default is the name of your VM in this case. If you have other vagrant boxes then these would be listed separately. Edited my post above to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

To completely clean VM and start from fresh - the below worked for me - basically combination of what others have said already.

1. Check VM status with vagrant locally and destroy if exists - all done inside vagrant folder - MAKE SURE you are in the correct folder!

   ```
   $ vagrant status
   $ vagrant destroy
   $ rm -rf .vagrant
   ```
2. Check VM status with vagrant globally and "destroy" if exists - can be done from anywhere

   ```
   $ vagrant global-status
   $ vagrant global-status --prune
   ```
3. Check VM status with VirtualBox's perspective and unregister VM

   ```
   $ vboxmanage list vms   
   ### note down long id, eg. c43266e6-e22b-437a-8cc1-541b7ed5c4b

   $ vboxmanage unregistervm <long id> --delete
   ```
4. Go back into appropriate vagrant folder and start VM

   ```
   $ vagrant up
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To destroy the vagrant you may try these simple steps:

1. You need to exit the ssh if you are already running vagrant ssh command you can type in exit to come out of vagrant ssh.
2. Once you are out of vagrant type:

```
vagrant destroy -f.
```

If these don't work out for you you may try it using bash.

Jump into the project folder where your actual code resides. Right-click and press git bash here. You will see a bash window popping up so just type in the same command in bash window: `vagrant destroy -f`.

I hope these simple steps work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

check the folder ./.vagrant/machines, and delete the ones you no longer need